# Are there negative repercussions from resigning without notice?

Tags: resignation, termination, notice-period

I would like to resign from my role at a multi-national corporation immediately, without notice. I’m worried, however, that this could impact my future opportunities, especially an opportunity in government that I am currently preparing for.

What are the possible repercussions of resigning without notice? How can I mitigate these in my current and future job searches?

Comment: How long have you been there?

Comment: What is your location? In the UK leaving without notice would be breach of contract. In Germany, it would be breach of company + the company is totally pissed off + makes you pay for it.

Comment: And in India, you may never get the paperwork that’d allow you to easily get another job.

Comment: Reading the original text, which uses "MNC" and "absconding" and talks about preparing for government exams, it is likely that this question is about India, which has its own rules enforcing giving notice.

Comment: I am voting to close because the lack of a location makes the question unclear. I would vote to reopen if a location were added.

Comment: Let’s reopen this - the question is direct and it isn’t directly answered by other questions.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you should consider before making the decision to resign without notice. Regardless, **the best thing to do is discuss your situation with your manager or a trusted leader in the organization and see if a reasonable compromise can be reached.**

If you choose to leave without notice and without discussing your concern with members of the organization, you should be mindful of:

1. **Local regulations:** There may be local regulations or other policies (e.g., of a labor union) that compel you to serve the notice period or penalize you for not providing notice. Questions about regulations should be directed to a local expert.
2. **Relationship with your employer:** Leaving on good terms is always the best thing to do if possible. Giving no notice and making no attempt to resolve the situation cooperatively with your employer is an easy way to spoil a potential reference and chances of returning to the organization.
3. **Relationship with your colleagues:** Seeing a coworker depart without a chance to transition work and say goodbye can leave your colleagues frustrated and resentful.
4. **Perception of potential employers:** Future employers are almost certain to see departing without notice as a major red flag. I would be very hesitant to hire someone who has done so without an understandable reason - it signals an attitude of non-cooperation to me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no contract or regulation requiring you to work your notice period, the main repercussion of resigning without notice is that is is extremely unprofessional.  It will be noted by coworkers and managers as a significant problem with you.  It will be mentioned if a future employer calls for a reference, and will be mentioned informally in networking by those coworkers and managers.  That company will not rehire you and it will be seen as a big black mark by future employers who find out.

If you don’t plan to use this company as a reference and don’t plan to work with any of these people again or people they talk with, then there will not be any external drawback, just the damage you do yourself by teaching yourself to behave unprofessionally.